# gfortran: polymorphic array with an array component

Tags: fortran, polymorphism, gfortran

The following

```
 type t
   real :: r(2)
 end type t

 class(t), allocatable :: array(:)

 allocate(array(1))
 array(1)%r(1) = 1
 array(1)%r(2) = 2
 print*,array(1)%r
end program
```

prints incorrectly

```
1.00000000       0.00000000
```

with gfortran-4.8.1. Regardless of the array size I can only correctly set the first element. All other assignments have no effect. No warning is given. Is this a compiler bug? With Intel compiler it prints correctly

```
1.000000       2.000000
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, the above, while possibly a compiler bug, is an oversimplification of my actual problem. In reality I have an allocatable array whose elements inherit from an abstract type.

```
module m
  type, abstract :: base
     real, allocatable :: r(:)
   contains
     procedure :: print
  end type base

  type, extends(base) :: t
  end type t

contains
  subroutine print(this, n)
    class(base) :: this
    integer n
    print*,this%r(n)
  end subroutine print
end module m

program test

  use m

  class(base), allocatable :: array(:)
  type(t) :: f

  allocate(array(1), mold=f)
  allocate(array(1)%r(2))
  array(1)%r(1) = 1.0
  array(1)%r(2) = 2.0
  call array(1)%print(1)
  call array(1)%print(2)
end program test
```

Result is

```
   1.00000000    
   0.00000000
```

with gfortran but should be

```
   1.00000000    
   2.00000000
```

as it is with ifort. Using a base-bound set function, instead of directly defining 'r', yields the correct results.
Anything non-standard in the above code or just a compiler bug?

**UPDATE**

This issue seems to be resolved now. I don't when a fix was introduced, but with GFortran 10.2.0 I get the correct behavior.

Comment: Try, if you haven't already, printing the two elements of `r` explicitly.  It sure looks like a compiler issue to me, but perhaps not with the allocation of `array` and assignment to `r`.

Comment: Printing the elements explicitly removes the problem. However, after a long day of debugging I found that was not the real issue (see the edit).